# Why does Android Studio doesn't accept my ImageButton's id

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a project. I want to give my image button an id but android studio doesnt accept it. it only accepts search_button or search_bar like this things. But if i give another name to it like search_btn it says cannot resolve symbol. And if i give it name search_button i cant find the id of it in java findviewbyid

There is a example of picture

[image: Picture of it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned and rebuild the project and it solved